# FullCalendar not events curl up

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Why are my full calendar event does not curl up. If I have more than three events should curl up and show at the bottom of the "more events". FullCalendar downloaded from the repository adesigns / calendar-bundle. I have this:

[image]

I need this:

[image]

This is my code.I added a piece of code at the end of the function but is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({


                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay, add_event'
                },
                lazyFetching: true,
                timeFormat: {
                    // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
                    agenda: 'H:mm', // 5:00 - 6:30

                    // for all other views
                    '': 'H:mm'         // 7p
                },
                eventSources: [
                    {

                        url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
                        type: 'POST',

                        // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
                        data: {
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
                        }
                    }
                ],
                monthNames: ['Styczeń', 'Luty', 'Marzec', 'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec', 'Lipiec', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Sty', 'Luty', 'Marz', 'Kwie', 'Maj', 'Czer', 'Lip', 'Sier', 'Wrze', 'Paź', 'Lis', 'Gru'],
                dayNames: ['Niedziela', 'Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Niedziela', 'Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota'],
                buttonText: {
                    month: 'Miesiąc',
                    week: 'Tydzień',
                    day: 'Dzień'
                },
                eventLimit: true, 
                views: {
                    agenda: {
                        eventLimit: 3 
                     }
                },
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I never heard of the plugin, I googled for the documentations, I opened the documentation and this was the first page I found that resembled your problem: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/

You need to add an event limit to your options that limit the amount of events on a day. Like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
    views: {
        agenda: {
            eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
        }
    }
});
```

If this does not solve your problem, please post the javascript code you are using. If this did solve your problem, please read the docs of this plugin before asking questions about it here.